# how to render Amazon Pay API V2 button from typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-pay

Here I am trying to integrate Amazon Pay Button in my angular application. Situation is that on which element I want to render button is inside an markup component, where I can't add script. So i have added it using another service FYI:Sucessfully. But still I got an **error:Property 'Pay' does not exist on type 'amazon'.ts(2339)** How can I resolve it?

Edit:
I found out that it was using wrong typings.d.ts file which was for old widget. Now I have removed it. And getting another error: **Cannot find name 'amazon'.ts(2304).** **I want to know how can I add type for Pay With Amazon API-v2?**

`<div id="AmazonPayButton"></div>`

```
renderAmazonPayButton(){
    amazon.Pay.renderButton('#AmazonPayButton', {
      // set checkout environment
      merchantId: environment.awsClientId,
      publicKeyId: environment.publicKeyId,
      ledgerCurrency: 'USD',
      // customize the buyer experience
      checkoutLanguage: 'en_US',
      productType: 'PayAndShip',
      placement: 'Product',
      buttonColor: 'Gold',
      // configure Create Checkout Session request
      createCheckoutSessionConfig: {
        payloadJSON: JSON.stringify(this.payload),
        signature: this.signature,
        algorithm: this.algorithm
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Based on the error, it seems like you're either not including the [JS library](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-checkout/add-the-amazon-pay-button.html#1-add-the-amazon-pay-script) or the library isn't getting loaded prior to the renderAmazonPayButton invocation.  Pay is defined in [this library](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-checkout/add-the-amazon-pay-button.html#1-add-the-amazon-pay-script)

Comment: Hey script is successfully loaded as it is visible in developer tool. <script type="text/javascript" src="https://static-na.payments-amazon.com/checkout.js" async=""></script>

Comment: The script is likely loading after this function is being called.  I'd make sure you load the JS library prior to any event or rendering that would invoke renderAmazonPayButton()